# after signing up it still shows sign up

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) && empty($_SESSION['email'])) {
?>
    <a class="more float_l" href="signup.php">Sign Up/Login</a>
<?php
} else {
?>
    <a class="more float_l" href="post/logout.php">Logout</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

now its working correctly when user is not logged in it displays sign up or login and when user is login it redirect to home.php and displays logout button but problem is that when someone signup and redirect to home.php it still displays sign up or login, please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you provide the login code?

Comment: $_SESSION['email'] is not being set, without seeing your code of how you are attempting to set it we can't help.

Comment: use the same and proper conditionals for all pages using sessions and make sure you've started the session in all of them.

Comment: i have created dynamic header which is linked to every page so it apply on all of them @Fred-ii-

Comment: which login code i should provide one where i created login function or where i have done the above same thing for login which is working properly,

Comment: what @Kyle said makes sense; it's not set. What you could do is, if it is SET and NOT EMPTY, show them something, ELSE, show them the login page.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Plus, I noticed `href="signup.php"` and `href="post/logout.php"` one has a folder and the other doesn't, *why?*

Comment: thanks everyone with your help i found my mistake that i had not created $_SESSION''s in sign up function

Comment: found that after using error reporting, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities of what may have gone wrong, ignoring the the fact that you didn't provide the Login Script:

1. The Login Script did not set the $_SESSION['email'] correctly or left it empty; or
2. You miss session_start(); in your Login Script and/or in this one.

I have edited your Script a bit, hopefully this may work better:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && !empty($_SESSION['email'])):
?>
    <a class="more float_l" href="post/logout.php">Logout</a>
<?php
else:
?>
    <a class="more float_l" href="signup.php">Sign Up/Login</a>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: thanks for help your code is correct but i have created a post file where i have taken values from database and i have used session_start(); actually i found my mistake that i had not created $_SESSION''s in sign up function